# Jade: Conditional statement not working correctly: not comparing at all

Tags: node.js, pug

I have this conditional statement in my .jade template:

```
- var merchant = "{{merchant}}"
if merchant == "The Restaurant"
    h1 It worked!
else
    h1 "{{merchant}}"
```

When I print '{{merchant}}' in my else statement, it comes out exactly as "The Restaurant". Thus, the condition should be evaluating to true.

when I re-work my code to so:

```
- var merchant = "The Restaurant"
if merchant == "The Restaurant"
    h1 It worked!
else
    h1 "{{merchant}}"
```

It actually works. I don't understand why the if condition is still evaluating to false. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Try removing the first line `- var merchant = "{{merchant}}"`

Comment: Okay, removed it. I then replaced merchant in the if statement with {{merchant}}, but now it gives me a syntax error. Suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you just remove the first line, nothing else?

Comment: nothing at all happens. No syntax error, no nothing. I mean, how is it supposed to know the value for merchant since it's not defined anywhere in the .jade file?

Comment: @Aweary I tried it. Still goes to the else condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Express.js and providing the `merchant` variable via the `res.render` method, then you don't need to declare the variable again. It will already be available in the rendering environment.

Jade also uses `#{}` for string interpolation, not `{{}}` like Handlebars. So change your code to the following, and it will work fine

```
if merchant == "The Restaurant"
    h1 It worked!
else
    h1 #{merchant}
```

I was able to get this working successfully with the following Express route

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { merchant: 'The Restaurant' });
});
```